# Error deploying my python telegram bot on heroku

Tags: python, heroku, telegram-bot

I'm making a Telegram bot on python and today i deployed it on Heroku. The bot had been deployed successfully but i'm having some troubles: first of all, i get an error when being redirected to my app's web page. After that i decided to check my app's logs, and i found this error:

```
telepot.exception.TelegramError: ('Conflict: terminated by other long poll or webhook', 409, {'ok': False, 'error_code': 409, 'description': 'Conflict: terminated by other long poll or webhook'})
```

I tried to see if the telegram bot was running, and it is, but instead of answering once to a command, it answer twice. The problem is not with the code, since when i run it locally from my ide, everything is alright.

I tried to find the problem, and i thought that it was another python script running on heroku, so i turned it off, but the problem was still there. I even thought that the script was running locally, but even with my laptop turned off, i get two answers.

Comment: Take a look at [this issue on telepot github page](https://github.com/nickoala/telepot/issues/15)

Comment: I'm using requests, so i assume that my problem is similar. Tried to add bot.setWebhook()  but it's still not working

Comment: Did you send a GET request to set the webhook before? You need to send a GET request to `https://api.telegram.org/bot[MYTOKEN]/setwebhook?url=[MYURL]` to setup the webhook.

Comment: Thanks! I just didn't understand what url i should put

Comment: Tried to delete the webhoock by going to https://api.telegram.org/bot[MYTOKEN]/setWebhook?url (no url in order to delete it) and it says that the webhoock was already deleted, it didn't solve the problem. Also, i tried to revoke the token and use a new one, it didn't work either,

Comment: That's strange, I cannot think of something else with the single line error you provide. Maybe having a double check on everything or re-start everything could help.